# Flutter auto route reevaluateListenable Work only once

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, auto-route

I am using reevaluateListenable to listen to my Settings Cubit Streem ( Auto route flutter package ), and it did but just one time, and not gonna work again until I refresh the app again.

here's my app.dart

```dart
class MizanitiApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MizanitiApp({super.key});

  final AppRouter router = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
            lazy: false,
            create: (context) => locator<SettingsCubit>()..initiated()),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => locator<WalletsWatcherCubit>()..initiated()),
      ],
      child: BlocConsumer<SettingsCubit, SettingsState>(
        listenWhen: (previous, current) =>
            previous.failureOrSuccessOption != current.failureOrSuccessOption,
        listener: (context, state) {
          state.failureOrSuccessOption.fold(
            () => null,
            (either) => either.fold(
              // failure
              (Failure failure) =>
                  _onSettingsFailure(context: context, failure: failure),
              // success
              (_) => _onSettingsSuccess(context: context),
            ),
          );
        },
        buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
            previous.domain.theme != current.domain.theme,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialApp.router(
            title: 'Mizaniti App',
            themeMode: state.domain.theme.getOrNull(),
            darkTheme:
                ThemeData(useMaterial3: true, brightness: Brightness.dark),
            theme: ThemeData(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
              useMaterial3: true,
            ),
            routerConfig: router.config(
                reevaluateListenable: ReevaluateListenable.stream(
                    context.read<WalletsWatcherCubit>().stream)),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my Guard

```dart
class BiometricGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) async {
    final BuildContext? context = router.navigatorKey.currentContext;

    optionOf(context).fold(
      () => resolver.next(),
      (context) {
        print('fingerprint');
        final bool isAppGuarded =
            context.read<SettingsCubit>().state.isAppGuarded;

        if (isAppGuarded) {
          router.replaceAll([const BiometricGuardRoute()]);
          return;
        }

        resolver.next();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Not sure if my solution is actually a correct one, but I managed to solve it by adding `resolver.next(false)` before forcing redirect by `resolver.redirect(const LoginRoute())` in my case.

Here is my code if you are interested.

```
@override
void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) async {
  if (router.isRoot) {
    switch (notifier.status) {
      case AuthStatus.loggedOut:
        if (resolver.routeName != LoginRoute.name) {
          resolver.next(false);
          resolver.redirect(LoginRoute(onResult: (p0) {}));
          return;
        }
      case AuthStatus.none:
        if (resolver.routeName != SplashRoute.name) {
          resolver.next(false);
          resolver.redirect(const SplashRoute());
          return;
        }
      case AuthStatus.loggedIn:
        if (resolver.routeName != HomeRoute.name) {
          resolver.next(false);
          resolver.redirect(const HomeRoute());
          return;
        }
    }
  }
  resolver.next();
}
```